# concatenate arrays on axis=3 while first dimension is different

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, concatenation

l have about 20 different data shape. l would like to concatenate them on `axis=3`

```
data_1=dim(1000,150,10)
data_2=dim(1000,150,10)
data_3=dim(1000,150,10)
data_4=dim(1000,150,10)
```

and

```
features_1=dim(1000,150,10)
features_2=dim(1000,150,10)
features_3=dim(1000,150,10)
features_4=dim(1000,150,10)
```

l concatenate them  to `data` and `features`  variable

hence

```
data.shape= (4,1000,150,10)
```

and

```
features.shape=(4,1000,150,10)
```

**What l want to do ?**

concatenate  data and features  on **axis=3** in a variable called `data_concat`

so that `data_concat.shape=(4,1000,150,20)`

to do so l did the following :

```
data_concat = np.concatenate((data,features),axis=3)
```

However when it doesn't work when the first dimension is not the same . For instance :

```
data_1=dim(1000,150,10)
data_2=dim(1200,150,10)
data_3=dim(800,150,10)
data_4=dim(400,150,10)
```

and

```
features_1=dim(1000,150,10)
features_2=dim(1200,150,10)
features_3=dim(800,150,10)
features_4=dim(400,150,10)
```

hence

```
data.shape= (4,)
```

and

```
features.shape=(4,)
```

Doing :

```
data_concat = np.concatenate((data,features),axis=3)
```

doesn't work because concatenate doesn't see axis=3 since

data.shape= (4,)

and

```
features.shape=(4,)
```

Thank you

Comment: I find the first sentence very confusing, especially considering that you follow it with arrays for which axis=3 is not defined. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Your `data` array is shape (4,) with 3d elements.  It's an object dtype array.  For this purpose you have to treat it as a list of arrays.  Some numeric operations propagate to the component arrays, but concatenate does not.

Answer (score 1):

Due to all the mathematical assumptions underlying them, numpy arrays must have a clearly defined shape. If that's not the case, numpy defines an array of lists, as it is the case with your second example: As you have noticed, here you can not use `np.concatenate` on `axis=3` because the array is treated as uni-dimensional.

Maybe, you could get something closer to your intention if you concatenate separately each `data` variable with its corresponding `features` variable like

```
df_1 = np.concatenate((data_1, features_1), axis=2)
df_2 = np.concatenate((data_2, features_2), axis=2)
df_3 = np.concatenate((data_3, features_3), axis=2)
df_4 = np.concatenate((data_4, features_4), axis=2)

data = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]
```

From your data, however, I notice that second and third dimension are always the same. This looks to me like you are trying to put together several batches of different length containing the same data. If that's the case, why not concatenating `data_1`, `data_2` ecc. on the 0-th axis? That would create no problem to numpy.

Comment: Hi. all what l have is data and features which are of shape (4,). l gave an example of data_1, data_2.. features_1,features_2 ... just for clarification to show that my data  differ only at the first dimension which is the number of examples BUT all of them have the same length  in the remaining dimensions

Comment: the purpose at the end is to concatenate  on the thrid axis  10+10=20 from data and features

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have 4 pairs of `data_i` and `features_i` variables where `i` runs from 1 to 4. Let's focus just on the `data_i` ones. Each `data_i` is a matrix with shape `(n_i, m, l)`, where `m` and `l` are constant but `n_i` changes. You want to concatenate these `data_i` to make a `data_concat` with shape... ?

Comment: Notice when happens when you define `data` in the second case of your example, where you have 4 different dimensions `n_i`: its shape is `(4,)`. This means that `data` is an array of lists. This happens because numpy can't treat it as a 4-dimensional array since not all the dimensions match.

Comment: My suggestions is to think of the structure you have. Either concatenate separately each `data_i` with its `features_i` before creating the list comprehension, or think if it's possible to concatenate on the axis of different length.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done either by list comprehension or if the result should be an array with `np.frompyfunc`:

```
# create example
>>> data = np.array([np.arange(n*12).reshape(n, 2, 6) for n in range(2, 5)])
>>> features = np.array([np.ones((n, 2, 6), int) for n in range(2, 5)])
>>> data.shape, features.shape
((3,), (3,))
>>> 
# list comprehension
>>> [np.concatenate(xy, 2) for xy in zip(data, features)]
[array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]]), array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]]), array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]])]

# frompyfunc
>>> np.frompyfunc(lambda *xy: np.concatenate(xy, 2), 2, 1)(data, features)
array([array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]]),
       array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]]),
       array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]],

       [[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]])], dtype=object)
```